# Is there an easy-ish front end software for Google Cloud?

Tags: gui, gui-builder, cloud, google

I have data in BigQuery and/or BigTable. Is there software that will produce a front end to this data? In the past I have used for frontends:

1. React- nightmare of complexity.
2. Plotly Dash - easier but gets tricky quite quickly.
3. Google Data Studio - easy but not very flexible.

So anything that sits at about 2.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a business intelligence tool, have a look at [Metabase](https://github.com/metabase/metabase).

If you need more flexibility, maybe try using [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) in your frontend app.

Also, keep in mind that you can create custom components in Data Studio by writing some [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), and in Dash by [writing them in React](https://dash.plotly.com/plugins).

Answer (score 0):

As you are on GCP I suggest you https://datastudio.google.com/ .

Or any Power BI or Tableau or similar software...